# Symfony 5.0 and KnpMenuBundle - how to configure

Tags: symfony, knpmenubundle, knpmenu, symfony5

In a Symfony 5.0 Application I want to use the KnpMenuBundle.
I installed it by running

```
composer require knplabs/knp-menu-bundle "^3.0"
```

This automatically created an entry in [ProjectRoot]/config/bundles.php":

```
Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle::class => ['all' => true]
```

Of course it downloaded the bundle as well.

The documentation (found at: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/index.html) states to configure the bundle one should edit the file "app/config/config.yml". Symfony 5 does not have this file anymore - but single config files for each "package" in "[ProjectRoot]/config/packages".
However there wasn't a config file created for KnpMenuBundle. How could I do this myself - meaning: Whats the naming conventions and how do I tell the bundle to actualy use the config file?

There is another issue.
In the documentation it says rendering a Menu in a twig template works like this:

```
{{ knp_menu_render('AppBundle:Builder:mainMenu') }}
```

For Symfony 5 - what would be the right syntax / path there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration for KnpMenuBundle is optional. That is why there is no configuration file created.
In Symfony 4 and 5 you can just add a yaml config file in the config/packages directory manually. It will be automatically read. A good name for this file could be knp_menu.yaml. Inside the config file you use the same content as documented. e.g.

```
knp_menu:
    twig:
        template: KnpMenuBundle::menu.html.twig
```

To render the menu you can use

```
{{ knp_menu_render('App:Builder:mainMenu') }}
```

Where Builder is the name of the class inside the src/Menu directory and mainMenu is method to call from the class ([See the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/index.html#method-a-the-easy-way-yay)).

**UPDATE**

If i am not wrong you have to define the [Builder class as a service](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/menu_builder_service.html) from Symfony 4 which is slightly different. As you can read from the docs you will now render your menu giving the alias of the service e.g.

```
{{ knp_menu_render('main') }}
```

(Change all AppBundle occurrences to **App**).

Comment: In the linked doc there are 3 methods described to use the menu. I chose method a). But trying to render with {{ knp_menu_render('App:Builder:mainMenu') }} gets me this error: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Bundle "App" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the registerBundles() method of your App\Kernel.php file?").

Comment: But you also said Symfony 4 / 5 require me to use the Builder Class service way - so I probably just have to switch to that.

Comment: Properly yes. It worked for me a while ago on Symfony 4.

Comment: So - I can't say for sure if it can't work with method a) - however it DOES work with method b) which is the menu builder way. So thanks for that.

Comment: It does look like your suggestion how to provide a config-file works too - as it gives an error as soon as I use it like you said. But it says: "Unable to find template "KnpMenuBundle::menu.html.twig" (looked into: ...)" Trying to load "knp_menu.html.twig" which definitely exists in the vendors path where it looks doesn't change anything. Any idea what the issue is here?

Comment: OK - the config file works like you suggest. However - I can't figure out how to change your example to actualy work. It just does not find the template using this notation. What would be the right way of writing this?